# Comparison between cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Denote $\{0,1\}^{X}=\{f\colon X\to\{0,1\}\}$.

If the cardinality of $X$ and $Y$ is the same, that is $$|X|=|Y|,$$ can we conclude that $$|\{0,1\}^X|=|\{0,1\}^Y|.$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let $g:Y\to X$ be a bijection and consider $\Phi:\{0,1\}^X\to\{0,1\}^Y$ given by $\Phi(f)=f\circ g$, for $f:X\to\{0,1\}$. Do you see why $\Phi$ is bijective?

Some more details as asked in the comments:
Suppose that $\Phi(f)=\Phi(h)$ for two functions $f,h\colon X\to\{0,1\}$.
This means that $f\circ g=h\circ g$, so we get $f=h$ by composing both sides with $g^{-1}$ (which exists since $g$ is bijective). In particular this shows that $\Phi$ is injective.

Consider now any $h\in\{0,1\}^Y$, to show that $\Phi$ is surjective we want to find an $f\in\{0,1\}^X$ such that $\Phi(f)=h$. But $f=h\circ g^{-1}$ works, so $\Phi$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Forgive me but I can't formally show what you asked me. Could you help me out?

Comment: @JackJ. I added some details